# Pytorch Reproducible - torch_scatter: can not be reproducible?

Tags: pytorch

I am a training a GNN model using Pytorch. I set the seed to a constant, but still can not get the same training results. I used torch_scatter. Is the scatter function can not be reproducible? If it can not be reproducible, what can I do? Please help me. Thanks very much.

```
from torch_scatter import scatter
out = scatter(agg_embed, index, dim=0, out=None, dim_size=t_embed.size, reduce='mean')
```